# How can this be resolved?

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers

> 953. Verifying an Alien Dictionary
>
> In an alien language, surprisingly they also use english lowercase
> letters, but possibly in a different order. The order of the alphabet
> is some permutation of lowercase letters.
>
> Given a sequence of words written in the alien language, and the order
> of the alphabet, return true if and only if the given words are sorted
> lexicographicaly in this alien language.

code

```
class Solution
{
public:
    static vector<pair<char, int>> dict;

public:
    static bool compare(string tst1, string tst2)
    {
        if (tst1 == tst2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        int l1 = tst1.size();
        int l2 = tst2.size();
        int n = min(l1, l2);
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (tst1[i] == tst2[i])
                continue;
            if (tst1[i] != tst2[i])
            {
                flag = 1;
                int a = 0, b = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
                {
                    if (tst1[i] == dict[j].first)
                        a = dict[j].second;
                    if (tst2[i] == dict[j].first)
                        b = dict[j].second;
                    if (a != 0 && b != 0)
                        break;
                }
                if (a > b)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

public:
    bool isAlienSorted(vector<string> &words, string order)
    {
        int n = words.size();
        vector<string> comp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            comp.push_back(words[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            dict.push_back(make_pair(order[i], i + 1));
        }
        sort(words.begin(), words.end(), compare);
        int flag = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (words[i] != comp[i])
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

error->

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Solution::dict
>>> referenced by prog_joined.cpp
>>>               /tmp/prog_joined-0fc27f.o:(Solution::isAlienSorted(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >))
>>> referenced by prog_joined.cpp
>>>               /tmp/prog_joined-0fc27f.o:(Solution::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >))
>>> referenced by prog_joined.cpp
>>>               /tmp/prog_joined-0fc27f.o:(Solution::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >))
>>> referenced 1 more times
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why am I getting this error? I am not able to understand.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/verifying-an-alien-dictionary/

Comment: why did you make all members `static`? If this is for LeetCode, they will create only one object of your `Solution` anyhow and you also don't create other instances

Comment: Btw despite your comparator is wrong and you need to fix it, you do not need a copy of vector and use `std::sort()` as there is `std::is_sorted()` algo that does what you need with the same comparator (when you implement it properly)

Comment: @Slava thanks for the info. I got your point..